# What is Event Listener in Selenium Webdriver [ java ]

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am Novice to Selenium web driver and java and how to implement in Selenium Script

Comment: Event listener is common thing, when an event is fired the frameworks would invoke methods of particular event listener and all of its implementations. I don't know Selenium but this is pretty generic question, if you search internet, you should get many examples...

Answer (score 1):

> Listeners “listen” to the event defined in the selenium script and
>   behave accordingly. The main purpose of using listeners is to create
>   logs and reports

Create a class `WebEventListener` which implements `WebDriverEventListener` and probably you can add following code

```
public void beforeNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Before navigating to: '" + url + "'");
}

public void afterNavigateTo(String url, WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Navigated to:'" + url + "'");
}

public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Value of the:" + element.toString() + " before any changes made");
}

public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Element value changed to: " + element.toString());
}

public void beforeClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Trying to click on: " + element.toString());
}

public void afterClickOn(WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Clicked on: " + element.toString());
}

public void beforeNavigateBack(WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Navigating back to previous page");
}

public void afterNavigateBack(WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Navigated back to previous page");
}

public void beforeNavigateForward(WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Navigating forward to next page");
}

public void afterNavigateForward(WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Navigated forward to next page");
}

public void onException(Throwable error, WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Exception occured: " + error);
    try {
        TestUtil.takeScreenshotAtEndOfTest();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void beforeFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Trying to find Element By : " + by.toString());
}

public void afterFindBy(By by, WebElement element, WebDriver driver) {
    System.out.println("Found Element By : " + by.toString());
}

/*
 * non overridden methods of WebListener class
 */
public void beforeScript(String script, WebDriver driver) {
}

public void afterScript(String script, WebDriver driver) {
}

public void beforeAlertAccept(WebDriver driver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void afterAlertAccept(WebDriver driver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void afterAlertDismiss(WebDriver driver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void beforeAlertDismiss(WebDriver driver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void beforeNavigateRefresh(WebDriver driver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void afterNavigateRefresh(WebDriver driver) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void beforeChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver, CharSequence[] keysToSend) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void afterChangeValueOf(WebElement element, WebDriver driver, CharSequence[] keysToSend) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public <X> void afterGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> arg0, X arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void afterGetText(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1, String arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void afterSwitchToWindow(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public <X> void beforeGetScreenshotAs(OutputType<X> arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void beforeGetText(WebElement arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

public void beforeSwitchToWindow(String arg0, WebDriver arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

Then create object of above class in Base class

```
eventListener = new WebEventListener();
eventdriver.register(eventListener);
driver = eventdriver;
```

Comment: @Manoj Patel If this helped you to solve t problem, could you please accept the answer?

Comment: WebDriverEventListener is deprecated, use EventFiringDecorator and WebDriverListener instead https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/events/WebDriverEventListener.html